# Ion-icon intermediate states with ng-class on mobile change the color of it

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-class

I implemented a pin/unpin button that updates the db in real time (using firebase with angularfire).

HTML code is the following:

```
<a class="button button-icon energized icon"
        ng-class="{'ion-ios-star-outline': !isPinned, 'ion-ios-star': isPinned}"
        ng-click="doUpdatePinForUid(user.auth.uid, !isPinned)"></a>
```

isPinned variable is synchronized with a value in DB.

This works perfectly in my browser but as soon as I emulate the app on iOS the change of icon from outline to plain goes through intermediate states that display it grey...

[image]

1. User is not pinned : star is outline and energized
2. I click the button, my user gets pinned : star is plain and grey (yet it should be energized to ; works in a browser not in iOS)
3. I have to click outside of the button (in a white space in the view) so that the button becomes energized (only on iOS)

I tried to debug it and the grey color seems to appear because of the different status the button goes through with the ng-class thing :

- ion-ios-star-remove-active
- ion-ios-star-add
- ion-ios-star-add-active
- ...

For information, I tried to update the isPinned variable in my controller by surrounding it in a $timeout because I initially though it was related to the digest cycle, but no.

Any help or suggestion ?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this

Comment: @noor I am not using Ionic 1/AngularJS anymore so I am not sure but I think I had to override the `:hover` css selector: `.button.energized:hover {color: #FFCD01;}` Let me know if this work, in this case I will post an answer to close the thread.